# Jinja2 macros argument doesn't expand

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I have a macro that's defined like this:

```html
{% macro render_row (class_suffix, form, field) %}
<div class="form-{{ class_suffix }}__row">{{ form.field.label }} {{ form.field() }}</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

I want to pass a `form` object and a `field` parameter to render a specific row, like this:

```html
{% import "macros.html" as macros %}
...
<div class="form-container">
    <h2>Sign In</h2>
    <form class="form-login" action="{{ url_for('signin') }}" method="post">
        {{ macros.render_row ('login', form, email) }}
        {{ macros.render_row ('login', form, password) }}
        {{ macros.render_submit ('login', 'Sign In') }}
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
    </form>
</div>
```

For example, `macros.render_row ('login', form, email)` should be expanded to:

```html
<div class="form-login__row">{{ form.email.label }} {{ form.email() }}</div>
```

Instead, I get this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'blog.forms.SignInForm object' has no attribute 'field'
```

Form's defined like this:

```py
class SignInForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email(), Length(max=64)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=8, max=64)])
```

I've also found a solution, but I'm curious why previous method doesn't work.

```html
{% macro render_row (class_suffix, form_field) %}
<div class="form-{{ class_suffix }}__row">{{ form_field.label }} {{ form_field() }}</div>
{% endmacro %}
...
{{ macros.render_row ('login', form.email) }}
```

Is it possible to do? What am I doing wrong? Is it even a good practice to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Jinja2 tries to get the property named `field` from the form object passed, not the field which name equals to the variable `field` passed.

It tries to do

```
{{ foo.field }}
{{ foo['field'] }}
```

But for your case, it will work only using this syntax, of course.

```
{{ foo[field] }}
```

Where `field` param for the macros should be a string I believe, now I think that's `None`.

So it should be

```
{{ macros.render_row ('login', form, 'email') }}
```

and the definition of the macro like

```
{% macro render_row (class_suffix, form, field) %}
<div class="form-{{ class_suffix }}__row">{{ form[field].label }} {{ form[field]() }}</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Check more details on the variable's syntax page https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#variables.

> I haven't tested it in real files, not have Jinja2 installed in my hands. But it should be working like that.

Comment: It works as expected. I'll probably stick with my solution tho. Thank you.